# Unable to load libraries using r-extension Netlogo

Tags: r, netlogo

I am unable to load packages using the r-extension in NetLogo. I seem to get the following error while running:

```
r:eval "library(rJava)"
```

Note:

1. The library is loaded while using R-32 bit console.
2. This is obviously assuming r - extension is loaded successfully in NetLogo and also i am able to run basic commands computations

> Extension exception: Error in R-Extension: Error in Eval: 
>   org.nlogo.api.ExtensionException: Error in library(rJava) : there is
>   no package called 'rJava'
>
> error while observer running R:EVAL   called by Command Center
>
> org.nlogo.nvm.EngineException: Extension exception: Error in
>   R-Extension: Error in Eval:  org.nlogo.api.ExtensionException: Error
>   in library(rJava) : there is no package called 'rJava'
>
> at org.nlogo.extension.r.Entry$Eval.perform(Entry.java:560)  at
>   org.nlogo.prim._extern.perform(_extern.java:54)  at
>   org.nlogo.nvm.Context.stepConcurrent(Context.java:91)  at
>   org.nlogo.nvm.ConcurrentJob.step(ConcurrentJob.java:82)  at
>   org.nlogo.job.JobThread.org$nlogo$job$JobThread$$runPrimaryJobs(JobThread.scala:143)
>   at
>   org.nlogo.job.JobThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobThread.scala:78)
>   at org.nlogo.job.JobThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobThread.scala:76) 
>   at org.nlogo.job.JobThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobThread.scala:76) 
>   at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:88)  at
>   org.nlogo.util.Exceptions$.handling(Exceptions.scala:41)  at
>   org.nlogo.job.JobThread.run(JobThread.scala:75)
>
> NetLogo 5.1.0 main: org.nlogo.app.AppFrame thread: JobThread Java
>   HotSpot(TM) Server VM 1.6.0_45 (Sun Microsystems Inc.; 1.6.0_45-b06)
>   operating system: Windows 8 6.2 (x86 processor) Scala version 2.9.2
>   JOGL: (3D View not initialized) OpenGL Graphics: (3D View not
>   initialized) model: ode
>
> 01:15:42.263 RuntimeErrorEvent (org.nlogo.app.App$$anon$1
>   (org.nlogo.window.GUIWorkspace)) AWT-EventQueue-0 01:15:42.232
>   AddJobEvent (org.nlogo.app.CommandLine) AWT-EventQueue-0 01:15:42.232
>   OutputEvent (org.nlogo.app.CommandLine) AWT-EventQueue-0 01:15:42.232
>   CompiledEvent (org.nlogo.window.CompilerManager) AWT-EventQueue-0
>   01:15:42.217 CompileMoreSourceEvent (org.nlogo.app.CommandLine)
>   AWT-EventQueue-0 01:15:42.154 PeriodicUpdateEvent
>   (org.nlogo.app.App$$anon$1 (org.nlogo.window.GUIWorkspace))
>   AWT-EventQueue-0 01:15:41.951 PeriodicUpdateEvent
>   (org.nlogo.app.App$$anon$1 (org.nlogo.window.GUIWorkspace))
>   AWT-EventQueue-0 01:15:41.748 PeriodicUpdateEvent
>   (org.nlogo.app.App$$anon$1 (org.nlogo.window.GUIWorkspace))
>   AWT-EventQueue-0 01:15:41.545 PeriodicUpdateEvent
>   (org.nlogo.app.App$$anon$1 (org.nlogo.window.GUIWorkspace))
>   AWT-EventQueue-0 01:15:41.138 PeriodicUpdateEvent
>   (org.nlogo.app.App$$anon$1 (org.nlogo.window.GUIWorkspace))
>   AWT-EventQueue-0

Comment: Common errors for such multi-package arrangements include incompatible package choices. You do not describe the versions of any of your package installations (although some of that detail is seen in your error report). The error says that rJava is not installed and you are saying (I think) that your R version is 32 bit which makes me wonder which version your Java code is accessing under Windows 8. What does a call to `sessionInfo()` return.

Comment: 1. Please see my post to this question: http://netlogo-users.18673.x6.nabble.com/loading-r-package-using-r-extension-td5005663.html

Comment: 2. I'm not sure if it is a good idea to load the rJava package from the R-Extension.